# python multiprocessing each with own subprocess (Kubuntu,Mac)

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, biopython

I've created a script that by default creates one multiprocessing Process; then it works fine. When starting multiple processes, it starts to hang, and not always in the same place. The program's about 700 lines of code, so I'll try to summarise what's going on. I want to make the most of my multi-cores, by parallelising the slowest task, which is aligning DNA sequences. For that I use the subprocess module to call a command-line program: 'hmmsearch', which I can feed in sequences through /dev/stdin, and then I read out the aligned sequences through /dev/stdout. I imagine the hang occurs because of these multiple subprocess instances reading / writing from stdout / stdin, and I really don't know the best way to go about this...
I was looking into os.fdopen(...) & os.tmpfile(), to create temporary filehandles or pipes where I can flush the data through. However, I've never used either before & I can't picture how to do that with the subprocess module. Ideally I'd like to bypass using the hard-drive entirely, because pipes are much better with high-throughput data processing!
Any help with this would be super wonderful!!

```
import multiprocessing, subprocess
from Bio import SeqIO

class align_seq( multiprocessing.Process ):
    def __init__( self, inPipe, outPipe, semaphore, options ):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.in_pipe = inPipe          ## Sequences in
        self.out_pipe = outPipe        ## Alignment out
        self.options = options.copy()  ## Modifiable sub-environment
        self.sem = semaphore

    def run(self):
        inp = self.in_pipe.recv()
        while inp != 'STOP':
            seq_record , HMM = inp  # seq_record is only ever one Bio.Seq.SeqRecord object at a time.
                                    # HMM is a file location.
            align_process = subprocess.Popen( ['hmmsearch', '-A', '/dev/stdout', '-o',os.devnull, HMM, '/dev/stdin'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
            self.sem.acquire()
            align_process.stdin.write( seq_record.format('fasta') )
            align_process.stdin.close()
            for seq in SeqIO.parse( align_process.stdout, 'stockholm' ):  # get the alignment output
                self.out_pipe.send_bytes( seq.seq.tostring() ) # send it to consumer
            align_process.wait()   # Don't know if there's any need for this??
            self.sem.release()
            align_process.stdout.close()
            inp = self.in_pipe.recv()  
        self.in_pipe.close()    #Close handles so don't overshoot max. limit on number of file-handles.
        self.out_pipe.close()
```

Having spent a while debugging this, I've found a problem that was always there and isn't quite solved yet, but have fixed some other *inefficiencies* in the process (of debugging).
There are two initial feeder functions, this align_seq class and a file parser **parseHMM()** which loads a position specific scoring matrix (PSM) into a dictionary.
The main parent process then compares the alignment to the PSM, using a dictionary (of dictionaries) as a pointer to the relevant score for each residue. In order to calculate the scores I want I have two separate multiprocessing.Process classes, one class **logScore()** that calculates the log odds ratio (with math.exp() ); I parallelise this one; and it Queues the calculated scores to the last Process, **sumScore()** which just sums these scores (with math.fsum), returning the sum and all position specific scores back to the parent process as a dictionary.
i.e.
    Queue.put( [sum, { residue position : position specific score , ... } ] )
I find this exceptionally confusing to get my head around (too many queue's!), so I hope that readers are managing to follow... After all the above calculations are done, I then give the option to save the cumulative scores as tab-delimited output. This is where it now (since last night) sometimes breaks, as I ensure it prints out a score for every position where there should be a score. I think that due to latency (computer timings being out-of-sync), sometimes what gets put in the Queue first for **logScore** doesn't reach **sumScore** first.
In order that sumScore knows when to return the tally and start again, I put 'endSEQ' into the Queue for the last logScore process that performed a calculation. I thought that then it should reach sumScore last too, but that's not always the case; only sometimes does it break. So now I don't get a deadlock anymore, but instead a KeyError when printing or saving the results.
I believe the reason for sometimes getting KeyError is because I create a Queue for each logScore process, but that instead they should all use the same Queue. Now, where I have something like:-

```
class logScore( multiprocessing.Process ):
    def __init__( self, inQ, outQ ):
        self.inQ = inQ
        ...

def scoreSequence( processes, HMMPSM, sequenceInPipe ):
    process_index = -1
    sequence = sequenceInPipe.recv_bytes()
    for residue in sequence:
        .... ## Get the residue score.
        process_index += 1
        processes[process_index].inQ.put( residue_score )
    ## End of sequence
    processes[process_index].inQ.put( 'endSEQ' )


logScore_to_sumScoreQ = multiprocessing.Queue()
logScoreProcesses = [ logScore( multiprocessing.Queue() , logScore_to_sumScoreQ ) for i in xrange( options['-ncpus'] ) ]
sumScoreProcess = sumScore( logScore_to_sumScoreQ, scoresOut )
```

whereas I should create just one Queue to share between all the logScore instances. i.e.

```
logScore_to_sumScoreQ = multiprocessing.Queue()
scoreSeq_to_logScore = multiprocessing.Queue()
logScoreProcesses = [ logScore( scoreSeq_to_logScore , logScore_to_sumScoreQ ) for i in xrange( options['-ncpus'] ) ]
sumScoreProcess = sumScore( logScore_to_sumScoreQ, scoresOut )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite how pipelining works... but to put your mind to ease, here's an excerpt from the [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the
>   executed programs’ standard input,
>   standard output and standard error
>   file handles, respectively. Valid
>   values are PIPE, an existing file
>   descriptor (a positive integer), an
>   existing file object, and None. PIPE
>   indicates that a **new pipe** to the child
>   should be created. With None, no
>   redirection will occur; the child’s
>   file handles will be inherited from
>   the parent.

The likeliest areas at fault would be in the communication with the main process or in your management of the semaphore.  Maybe state transitions / synchronization are not proceeding as expected due to a bug?  I suggest debugging by adding logging/print statements before & after each blocking call - where you're communicating with the main process and where you acquire/release the semaphore to narrow down where things have gone wrong.

Also I'm curious - is the semaphore absolutely necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So even though I reference /dev/stdin & /dev/stdout multiple times, each process gets their own instance of it, and there's no chance of them confusing one another?? Sweet! Looking further into the errors after killing (^C) the program, it seems the dead-lock arises with a multiprocessing.Queue. I've got a series of them which I picture as having a cascade, or knock-on effect by sending 'endSEQ', and finally 'STOP'. It took long enough to debug last month with one process. Trying to get my head back around it now, :(
And I don't think the semaphore is necessary. Gone :)

Comment: np!  The /dev/stdin & /dev/stdout files map to the special stdin & stdout file descriptors, so they don't represent a central device. --- I don't see use of the Queue in the align_seq child process, is it only used in the main process?  If so, then you can just use queue.Queue.  Also you say you suspect a deadlock - you're not consuming bidirectionally are you (main & child/ren)?

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying stdin /stdout. Now I think about it, kind of obvious in the way that I use them, but I've never seen it explicitly stated before. You're absolutely right; the Queue's are in a separate part of the program, which is where my deadlocks seem to appear. I'll update the main post because there's a lot more multiprocessing to the program I didn't originally state... Gonna reply to the below posts first though. I've got it now so that sometimes it finishes, and sometimes it breaks right near the end, which I guess is due to latency(??). time.sleep is my temp, dirty fix

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to parallelize simple tasks and for that I created a little python script. You can take a look at: 
http://bioinf.comav.upv.es/psubprocess/index.html

Is a little more general than what you want, but for simple tasks is quite easy to use. It might be at least of some insparation to you.

Jose Blanca

Comment: Nice looking website, and an impressive list of publications! Yea some inspiration & examples would be nice(!), as the multiprocessing module is a beast I'm just scratching the surface with so far! I'll be sure to take a look at psubprocess when I get a chance; this weekend will see me writing more than coding, as deadlines and meeting on Monday... Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a deadlock in subprocess, have you tried using the communicate method rather than wait?
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I avoid using communicate, because communicate will deadlock if the buffer gets filled, which it does very easily with huge sequence alignments (even when using the bufsize=-1 option), so I usually read the output as it is produced. A favourite method of mine has been to pass the Popen instance to a separate function which I dedicate to parsing the .stdout from whatever program is called. In the parent function, I'll check the return code, and if that's non-zero, then I'll read the stderr.